# Swift, UIButton's image disappeared

Tags: swift, image, uibutton

Swift application, Xcode 14.2. Target 16.2. I have UIButton in my storyboard with properties "Type: Custom, Style: Default". If I set an image from .xcassets file, on preview everything ok, on emulator also. But if I test it on real device, image is invisible (without image). Same thing can be reproduced on emulator, if  uncheck "debug executable" in "Edit Scheme" of Product. In every View controller the same problem, so I think it is something globally on application level.

My project is a copy from another old one. May be some applications settings are different or something else. May be somebody know correct way, where I should search.

Interesting moment, that if I create new empty application, just copy button with all properties, everything works OK - button shows correctly with Image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like poossibly when the image was added in the other project the asset was referencing s file outside of the project directory. So when you have copied the project you didn’t get the referenced file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is founded. Just need to remove extension of UIButton:

```
extension UIButton {
open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }}
```

It is working correctly on IOS 13, but have some bug on the latest versions.

Comment: Never attempt to override a function in an extension. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple reasons why the UIButton is not appearing when running the app on a real device ,

1. The issue might be caused by the image extension or a damaged image. Please try verifying the image in your browser first.
2. Check the added image to the correct target & that it is included in the project's build phases.
3. Clean the build folder and then build again. You can do this by going to the “Product” tab.
4. Check the image name in your asset folder.
5. Resetting the simulator or device & rebuilding the project.

I trust that this will assist you in resolving the matter.